# Android default email app, not sending links properly

Tags: android, email

The default android application for sending emails is not sending Links ("a href=") properly. When I try to send an email I can see the links highlighted but they are gone by the time the recipient gets them.

```
    Intent openInChooser;
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

    openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.share_app));

    context.startActivity(openInChooser);
```

Changing "text/plain" to "text/html" does not help.
Also, if I select "gmail" as the email client, the links get to the recipient well formated.
Any ideas why?. I know the default email app is able to send links because I forwarded some and they got through.

Comment: Is your email text HTML code that contains proper `<a>` tags for links?

Comment: yes, In fact, the links get through just fine if using gmail. :/

Comment: Is the default email app able to send html emails? Please provide a complete working example that we can copy, paste and test. You did not tell what the recipients see. Send it to an email reader on a pc so you have the possibility to see it as html or plain text or as source.